# How to Get Hard Drive Memory and CPU Usage of a VM Using Powershell

Tags: powershell, hyper-v

Is it possible to get the hard drive memory and CPU usage of a virtual machine without going inside the VM itself? If I use `Get-VM | fl *` to get all the available properties, I do not find any that resemble the HD memory or the CPU usage.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Measure-VM](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848471.aspx) and its 'requirement' [Enable-VMResourceMetering](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848481.aspx)

So essentially to enable it for all VMs you can execute

```
Get-VM | Enable-VMResourceMetering
```

and then to get actual resource metrics for the VMs you can execute

```
Get-VM | Measure-VM
```

Of course you can also disable it again with [Disable-VMResourceMetering](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/hh848498.aspx)

Comment: This was so helpful! Thanks a lot! I have one last question though. It seems that this command also gets the average resource usage of a VM. Would you have an idea how it was computed? Was it based from the last 1 month? 2 months?

Comment: Nice to hear :) - please accept the answer in this case  - thx

Comment: I have one last question though. It seems that this command also gets the average resource usage of a VM. Would you have an idea how it was computed? Was it based from the last 1 month? 2 months?

Comment: There is returned a property 'MeteringDuration' which specifies the duration the average is calculated on. See also the doc page https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848471.aspx for deeper details

Comment: Okay, thanks! I noticed that this command also showed the Total Disk usage. Is it also possible to extract the hard-disk memory that was assigned to the VM? I actually want to see the difference between the two.